# "IndexOf" function in ReactJS doesn't work like the vanilla JS approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a *counter app* that simply increment its component state.

This is the sandbox app link: https://codesandbox.io/s/5mxqzn001k .
You can see the **counters.indexOf(counter)** on file *src/components/counters.jsx* at **line 30** which finds the target object and set its new *value* and it worked.

```
handleIncrement = counter => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
};
```

I've tried to duplicate that function that finds the target object in vanilla js approach in this link:
https://repl.it/@stoic25/TrickyForsakenLamp but I'm wondering why it doesn't work?

```
const state = {
    counters: [
        { id: 1, value: 4 },
        { id: 2, value: 0 },
        { id: 3, value: 0 },
        { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
};

let myArr = state.counters.indexOf({ id: 4, value: 0 });
console.log( myArr );
// returns -1
```

Is ReactJS's "indexOf" function behavior is different from vanilla js?

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects are only equal to each other if they refer to the exact same instance of the object. If you pass the reference of object in the array to `indexOf` function, it will find the index by comparing reference but if you pass new object, it wont compare each key of the object to find the index of of object in the array. For your second example, try this and see it will work:

```
const state = {
  counters: [
    { id: 1, value: 4 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0 }
  ]
};
let obj=state.counters[3]
let myArr = state.counters.indexOf(obj);
console.log( myArr );
```

The counter object passed to `handleIncrement` function in your first react example, is a reference to an object in you `state.counters` hence it returns its index.

Comment: Thank you so much, I fully understand it now.